# Issue while running Spark application on Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a testing spark environment(Single Node) running on AWS. I executed few adhoc queries in PySpark shell and everything went as expected, however, when I'm running the application using **spark-submit** , I get error.

Below is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext as sql

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("myapp")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #inp_data = loaded data from db
    df = inp_data.select('Id','DueDate','Principal','delay','unpaid_emi','future_payment')
    filterd_unpaid_emi = df.filter(df.unpaid_emi == 1)
    par = filterd_unpaid_emi.groupBy('Id').sum('Principal').withColumnRenamed('sum(Principal)' , 'par')
    temp_df = df.filter(df.unpaid_emi == 1)
    temp_df_1 = temp_df.filter(temp_df.future_payment == 0)
    temp_df_1.registerTempTable("mytable")
    bucket_df_1 = sql("""select *, case
    when delay<0 and delay ==0 then '9999'
    when delay>0 and delay<7 then '9'
    when delay>=7 and delay<=14 then '8'
    when delay>=15 and delay<=29 then '7'
    when delay>=30 and delay<=59 then '6'
    when delay>=60 and delay<=89 then '5'
    when delay>=90 and delay<=119 then '4'
    when delay>=120 and delay<=149 then '3'
    when delay>=150 and delay<=179 then '2'
    else '1'
    end as bucket
    from mytable""")
    bucket_df_1 = bucket_df_1.select(bucket_df_1.Id,bucket_df_1.Principal,bucket_df_1.delay,bucket_df_1.unpaid_emi,bucket_df_1.future_payment,bucket_df_1.bucket.cast("int").alias('buckets'))
    min_bucket = bucket_df_1.groupBy('Id').min('buckets').withColumnRenamed('min(buckets)' , 'max_delay')
    joinedDf = par.join(min_bucket, ["Id"])
    #joinedDf.printSchema()
```

And below is the command to submit the application:

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--driver-class-path /path to/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar \
--jars /path to/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar \
/path to/mycode.py
```

**ERROR:**

```
17/11/10 10:00:34 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: mytable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path to/mycode.py", line 36, in <module>
    from mytable""")
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 73, in __init__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_jsc'
17/11/10 10:00:34 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/11/10 10:00:34 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at ........
```

I'm quite new to Spark so can someone please tell the mistake(s) i'm doing.?
Also, any feedback on improving coding style will be appreciated!

**Spark Version : 2.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the imported SQLContext as sql to query your temp table (which is not bound to any spark instances), not the `spark.sql` (from the initialized spark instance). I also, changed some of your imports and code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # move the initializations within the main
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("myapp")
    # create the session
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf) \
           .getOrCreate()

    # load your data and do what you need to do
    #inp_data = loaded data from db
    df = inp_data.select('Id','DueDate','Principal','delay','unpaid_emi','future_payment')
    filterd_unpaid_emi = df.filter(df.unpaid_emi == 1)
    par = filterd_unpaid_emi.groupBy('Id').sum('Principal').withColumnRenamed('sum(Principal)' , 'par')
    temp_df = df.filter(df.unpaid_emi == 1)
    temp_df_1 = temp_df.filter(temp_df.future_payment == 0)
    temp_df_1.registerTempTable("mytable")

    # use spark.sql to query your table
    bucket_df_1 = spark.sql("""select *, case
    when delay<0 and delay ==0 then '9999'
    when delay>0 and delay<7 then '9'
    when delay>=7 and delay<=14 then '8'
    when delay>=15 and delay<=29 then '7'
    when delay>=30 and delay<=59 then '6'
    when delay>=60 and delay<=89 then '5'
    when delay>=90 and delay<=119 then '4'
    when delay>=120 and delay<=149 then '3'
    when delay>=150 and delay<=179 then '2'
    else '1'
    end as bucket
    from mytable""")

    bucket_df_1 = bucket_df_1.select(bucket_df_1.Id,bucket_df_1.Principal,bucket_df_1.delay,bucket_df_1.unpaid_emi,bucket_df_1.future_payment,bucket_df_1.bucket.cast("int").alias('buckets'))
    min_bucket = bucket_df_1.groupBy('Id').min('buckets').withColumnRenamed('min(buckets)' , 'max_delay')
    joinedDf = par.join(min_bucket, ["Id"])
    #joinedDf.printSchema()
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Great! That helped. Is creating SparkSession using sc incorrect/Wrong approach?? sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

Comment: @Sumit Glad it helped! creating a `SparkSession` using sc was the way to do it in pre-2.0 versions of Spark. Since you are using Spark 2.2.0 the session can be created without the implicit use of a SparkContext, which makes it easier to use afterwards. [src](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html)